# Javascript event listener attaching to wrong element?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a DIV and attaching a mouseover event to it which works fine, however adding next bit of HTML using innerHTML triggers the mouse out event according the size of that DIV and not the DIV the event was attached to.

```
menu = document.createElement('DIV');
menu.id=menuId;
menu.style.height="50px";

menu.addEventListener('mouseout', function(menu) {
this.menu(menu);
}.bind(this,menu), false); 



this.html = '<div>heading</div><div>content</div>';

menu.innerHTML=this.html;

doc=document.body.firstChild;
document.body.insertBefore(menu,doc);
```

Comment: Children of the element still trigger event handlers, even if they are not physically "inside" the element. That's just how it works.

Comment: So I can't detect if the mouse leaves the container DIV without doing lots of pixel based detection?